# How to ground the below circuit when I use USB?

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, ground, grounding, biopotential

I am constructing the circuit given below:
[image]

The problem, however, is that when I connect the electrodes to my skin, I get a mild shock. I am powering the Arduino using an USB cable. I connected the grounds in the image to the Arduino's ground. I am guessing that the USB power is causing problems. Any suggestions on how to properly ground the Arduino? Also, I am not using any batteries in this circuit. The only power source is the USB cable that I use to power the Arduino. The +5 volt go to the Arduino's 5V pin and the ground ones go to the ground pin on the Arduino.

Comment: Without proper isolation, you should not be connecting this circuit to your body while it is connected to a USB port.

Comment: How then, do i provide the isolation? Any ideas?

Comment: Isolation is not hard to achieve, but it requires attention to detail and really is worth a question on its own. It's not something you're going to get using an Arduino board.

Comment: So then, should I just use the circuit as it is using resistors on the leads?

Comment: The 500k on each lead needs to be there. To meet medical safety directives, it should technically be 2x249k on each. I would never hook this up to my skin without proper isolation. If you're going to use it, I can't stop you. You're the one taking the risk.

Comment: You can purchase a USB isolator. There are several products on the market, but they may not be certified for medical applications.

Comment: But is the isolation absolutely necessary? Won't the resistors suffice?

Comment: Yes, for a certified device, the isolation is necessary. But as @MattYoung said, if you're only hooking this up to yourself, it's up to you decide how much risk is acceptable.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't hesitate to use this circuit unisolated with 500K resistors in there, but I would run it off of a USB hub to avoid frying my motherboard if I caused a problem.  This would probably test fine to NFPA99 standards, which just cares about the current the patient can see given failures, but not the full ISO med safety standard.  If I were to bring the device to the FDA for approval, the approach would need to be different, of course.

Comment: But I need the arduino to communicate with my PC so I need the USB hub

Answer (score 1):

Put 500kOhm resistors on each electrode lead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But are my ground connections correct? I don't want to damage the board.

Comment: @SwastikMohapatra  Yes, assuming that it is built as it your drawing

Comment: Just one more thing, I am using this to measure EEG signals. Won't a 500k resistor block those tiny signals?

Comment: @SwastikMohapatra -- no, the input resistance of the AD620 is very high.  I would suggest matching the resistors as closely as possible, or better yet, include the capacitors on the inputs that are shown in the data sheet for that integrated circuit.  Also, you don't seem to have a gain setting resistor for the AD620, and you will need one.

Comment: I know, the schematic is really horrible. I used a 2.2K resistor for an approximate gain of 23. So, according to you, I should add 2 capacitors as given in the data sheet?

Comment: @SwastikMohapatra -- yes, but that's more for control of noise than for anything else.

Comment: So then any suggestions on improving the gain? I am a newbie, so I guess my questions would look stupid. :P